# The grammar of 实事求是的石

Tags: translation, grammar

I actually want a tongue twister for practice.  But I want one that could be a Chinese sentence. Is the following at all acceptable as way to say "This is the 'seek truth through facts' rock"?

这就是实事求是的石.

By that I mean the rock on the Renmin University campus with the motto 实事求是.

On line I find nearly this, but always with 石额 or some other noun complement to 石.  Can I possibly do without that, or is 石 too much of a bound morpheme to allow that?

Comment: http://www.gmw.cn/01gmrb/2008-01/09/content_720360.htm
with picture of rock, only has 石 occurring 3 times: 巨石,石头,巨石, source for 石额?

Comment: 石 may be too much of a bound morpheme for the suggested 名词短语 to be easily understood without context

Comment: @user6065 Actually 巨石 is better for my purposes. Thanks. Anyway one source for 额 is gov.cn/jrzg/2007-09/26/content_762128.htm referring to an earlier inscription in Yan'an.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this to challenge your tongue.

四是四，十是十；十四是十四，四十是四十

Good luck with your tongue!

Answer (score 2):

It's okay grammatically, but not very challenging.

粗俗書生私下心想，「石上書寫『實事求是』四字似是敘寫世上數億心上思想，實屬喜事!」

Comment: Well, I thought of it for a thirteen year old just beginning Mandarin.  Maybe I'll work with yours!

Comment: ack, don't! 實屬喜事 alone left psychic scars on me that still haven't healed...

Comment: Then go with "吃葡萄不吐葡萄皮"--tongue twister level 1...